# How to increase original LLaMA2 inference speed?

Tags: large-language-model, llama

This question is about the original Meta LLaMA2 model that you download from Meta website. This question is **NOT ABOUT** Hugging Face (or any other) quantized modeles or quantization methods.

I have an advanced usecase that works with the original model, but does not work with all the other quantized modeles. The problem is that I can run only one inference at time. Batching also is not an option, because of max_seq_len considerations. When I try to call the model in parallel, all the inferences get blocked and take even longer to return, than if executed one by one.

So the question is simple, how can I make original LLaMA2 model to support multiple inferences in any way.

I run on single GPU RTX4090

I use the standard code:

```
generator = Llama.build(
    
    ckpt_dir="C:/AI/codellama/CodeLlama-7b-Instruct",
    tokenizer_path="C:/AI/codellama/CodeLlama-7b-Instruct/tokenizer.model",
    max_seq_len=max_seq_len,
    max_batch_size=max_batch_size,
    model_parallel_size = num_of_worlds
)

    
    results = generator.chat_completion(
        dialogs,  
        max_gen_len=max_gen_len,
        temperature=temperature,
        top_p=top_p,
    )
```

Comment: You are asking two questions: How to make it faster and how to run inference in parallel. I think these are in conflict, if you have a single GPU and it works on two tasks in parallel the speed of each one will be half as much at best. One hack for the parallelism would be segmenting the GPU into multiple VMs (IOMMU etc.) but that will be very memory inefficient.